# Как получить разницу между двумя срезами базы данных?

Tags: oracle, sql

Есть SQL база данных Oracle. База упрощенно состоит из одной таблицы. Разные клиенты могут независимо друг от друга добавлять в таблицу по строке. В каждый момент времени клиент может иметь срез базы данных (последние N строк таблицы). После чего другой клиент может обновить базу и необходимо синхронизировать копии.

Как получить список строк для обновления таблицы с момента последней синхронизации? Как действовать в случае произвольно сложной схемы базы данных?

Answer (score 2):

Кому интересно. Задача решается с помощью [Flashback Query](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/flashback-10g.php).

Например, чтобы получить строки таблицы, которые были добавлены после последнего обновления используем две выборки за разные даты и вычитаем результат одной из другой.

Текущая версия - исходная версия

```
SELECT * FROM table;

MINUS

SELECT * FROM table AS OF 
    TIMESTAMP (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '60' MINUTE);
```